# php foreach gone wrong

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in my database named tbl_grade

```
id  |  studentid  | compid | subcompid | recordid | termid | grade
1        101          1          1           1         1       95
2        101          1          2           1         1       80
3        102          1          1           1         1       90
4        102          1          2           1         1       95
5        103          2          2           1         1       90
```

I wish to print that in my view like this

```
studentid | grade in subcomp1 | grade in subcomp2 | total (of both grades)
   101              95                 80                  175
   102              90                 95                  185
```

To echo that in my view, I have this

```
<?php foreach ($this->UserModel->grades() as $grade): ?>
  <?php if($grade->compid=='1' && $grade->subcompid==$subcomp->id && $grade->recordid==$subcomp->recordid && $grade->studentid==$student->studentid && $grade->termid == '1'){ ?>
     <td class="text-center"><?php echo $grade->grade; ?></td>
  <?php }
endforeach; ?>
```

With that, I obtained what I want and was able to print the grades according to the students, but I have a problem in echoing the total. I have this code

```
<?php foreach ($this->UserModel->grades() as $grade): ?>
   <?php if ($grade->compid=='1' && $grade->studentid==$student->studentid && $grade->subcompid==$subcomp->id && $grade->recordid==$subcomp->recordid && $grade->termid == '1') { ?>
      <td class="colScore text-center"><strong>
         <?php 
         $mySum = 0;
           foreach ($this->UserModel->gradeSum($student->studentid) as $sum):
             if($sum->compid==1 && $sum->termid=='1'){
               $mySum = $mySum + $sum->grade;
             }
           endforeach; echo $mySum;?></strong>
      </td>
   <?php } 
endforeach; ?>
```

The codes inside the php tag are working, i can get the correct sum of the grades. However, the way it is outputted is like this

```
studentid | grade in subcomp1 | grade in subcomp2 | total (of both grades) |
   101    |         95        |        175        |          80            |  175
   102    |         90        |        185        |          95            |  185
```

It prints the total in every grade. The total should be just at the end. There might something wrong with my foreach loop? Where should I put it? I've been staring at it for hours z_z

*assume all the values are obtained correctly from the database

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually handle this in MySQL using a pivot query:

```
SELECT studentid,
       MAX(CASE WHEN subcompid = 1 THEN grade END) AS grade_in_subcomp1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN subcompid = 2 THEN grade END) AS grade_in_subcomp2,
       SUM(grade) AS total
FROM tbl_grade
GROUP BY studentid
```

Comment: But then again, why would you? ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry Emphasis on the _you_ part of that comment LOL.